# Gparted resize of an extended partition  fails with error "can't have overlapping partitions".

Tags: partitioning, usb, live-cd, gparted

I just decided to install Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows 7 on my Dell laptop. However I didn't do this manually but instead used the "*Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7*" option during the installation. Now the partition that Ubuntu runs in has very little space and I am getting warning messages.

I'm trying to use `gparted` 0.12.1-5 (via a live CD) to give Windows less space and give Ubuntu more. I've managed to remove 100GB from the Windows partition so I now have some unallocated space between Windows and Ubuntu.

This is what it looks like inside Ubuntu (not using the live CD, since it won't let me mount a USB to save a screenshot):

[image: screenshot of gparted showing drive's partitions]

So first I take `sda4` (extended?) and resize it to the left so it takes up all the unallocated space. Then I resize `sda5` (ext4) as well so it takes up all the new space.

However, when I hit apply, it fails on the first action (resizing `sd4`) with the error message `can't have overlapping partitions`.

Any ideas as to why this happens? I also tried resizing `sda4` by just a few MB so that it definitely didn't overlap anything, but I still got the same error message.

To clarify, I ***am*** using `gparted` from the LiveCD, I just took the screenshot from Ubuntu.

I couldn't attach the details file containing the error information from `gparted` because I can't mount a USB drive when I'm running from the LiveCD.

I'm tried following the guide on the `gparted` website but it says `Invalid argument` or something like that. If the `gparted` details are needed, I may need some hints on how to solve the USB issue as well. :)

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a good work around for when GParded failed with this error?

Answer (score 6):

The last post of this thread http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1980664 solved the problem for me.

> When looking at the dialog box for "resize/move dev/sda2" there is an option to change the alignment from MiB to Cylinder - click to change it and... Voilà! To resize my sda1 (windows), I had to switch back to MiB.

Answer (score 1):

This problem appears to be the same as the following bug report:

Bug #678831 - Partition End Overlap when Resizing Extended Partition

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=678831

This bug report is scheduled for inclusion in the upstream release of GParted 0.13.0 on Friday, July 13, 2012.

Comment: The GParted Live 0.13.0-beta1.3 is available upstream now.  The stable release of GParted Live is expected a few days after the application release date.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions.

1. You are probably already doing this, but I'll mention it "*just in case*".

   Before you attempt to resize `/dev/sda4` (or any partition inside of it), you must use `swapoff` within `gparted` to ensure that the swap partition, `/dev/sda6`, is unlocked.

   If you do not do this your LiveCD will automatically lock and use it. This would prevent you from changing it.
2. One way you could make a copy of the error results from `gparted` would be to copy the file onto your `sda5`, Ubuntu, partition.

   While using the LiveCD, open the file manager, mount the **Ubuntu** 2.87 GB partition by clicking on it, and then copy the `gparted` results file to `sda5`.

   For example, you could copy the file into your `/home/userid` or `/home/userid/Documents` directory. After you have made a copy, change the permissions of the copy to allow anyone to read and write to it. (This will allow you to work with the file without using `sudo`, later, when you are not using the LiveCD.
3. Your `swap` partition is 5.9 GiB while your `/` (Ubuntu) partition is only 2.87 GiB. *This is absurd.*

   The installer probably did this to you. It may have attempted to create a swap which was the same size as your memory. This is only important if you want to hibernate your machine. If you do **not** hibernate you can use a much smaller `swap` (or even no `swap` partition at all if you have 'enough' memory).

   I suggest you try the following using `gparted` after booting your LiveCD.

   - Ensure the `swap` partition is not locked. (See (1) above).
   - Delete the `swap` partition `/dev/sda6`.
   - Create a "new" `swap` partition no bigger than, say, 1 GiB (1024 MiB) at the END
     of the unallocated space inside `sda4`.
   - Resize your Ubuntu partition, `sda5`, to use the unallocated space now available in front of the new `swap` partition you created.

   The above steps should give you a few more GiB of breathing room for `sda5` until you can figure out why you cannot expand `sda4`.